# jQuery each calling AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am attempting to populate `<div></div>` elements via jQuery's `.each`. The elements are like the following:

```
<div id="failed" class="container" data-status="Fail"></div>
<div id="passed" class="container" data-status="Pass"></div>
```

jQuery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var baseUrl = "http://some.thing.local",

    $(".container").each(function () {
        var context = $(this),
            data = {
                status: context.data("status")
            };

        // to call http://some.thing.local?status=(Pass|Fail)
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: baseUrl,
            data: data
        }).success(function (html) {
            context.html(html);
        });
    });
});
```

The page loads and the URLs are called appropriately (as in the correct URL) but I end up with the same HTML in both elements being iterated over. Now, I have read and researched and I understand that because these are async calls, I am essentially overwriting my response to the one that finishes last which is why it is not working.

I am just trying to figure out the best way to do it instead. If anyone has any ideas, I'd be very appreciative if you could guide me.

Comment: I would suggest to pass the target div id in the request and send back in the response. So you would be able to find the context when the response complete. And then you can use the response's target id to populate the div.

Comment: I would suggest , in one api call , return both result in different arrays and then bind them in on success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a scoping issue. Maybe this helps:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var baseUrl = "http://some.thing.local",

    $(".container").each(function () {
        (function(scope) {
          var context = scope,
              data = {
                status: context.data("status")
              };

          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: baseUrl,
              data: data
          }).success(function (html) {
              context.html(html);
          });
        })($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: Scoping was part of the issue but the issue was that I am new to the .NET stack and didn't know you had to declare things as async and construct controllers as such. Basically my thread was getting overwritten. I set `async: false` and I'll fix the problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the callbacks are async but the assignment `var context = $(this)` is done synchronously, before the callbacks are called. Therefore, `context` settles to the value assigned to it during the last iteration and in all remaining callbacks (still to be executed) that last value is used.

You should bind the this context:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var baseUrl = "http://some.thing.local",

    $(".container").each(function () {
        var data = {
                status: context.data("status")
            };

        // to call http://some.thing.local?status=(Pass|Fail)
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: baseUrl,
            data: data
        }).success(function (html) {
            this.html(html);
        }.bind($(this)));
    });
});
```